# Wrapper function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I understand wrapper would be something like

```
var str = 'Hello World'; // assigning string to a variable
console.log(str); // 'Hello World'

var str2 = new String('Hello World') // Creating a wrapper function
str2.valueOf() // 'Hello World'
```

By that logic, can the below example also be considered a wrapper function

```
function SuperOuterAdd(a, b){
       console.log('Wrapper 2');
       return OuterAdd(a, b);
    }

    function OuterAdd(a, b){
       console.log('Wrapper 1');
       return add(a, b);
    }

    function add(a, b){
        return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
    }
```

Comment: No, it's not a wrapper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no language definition of *wrapper function* in JavaScript, and from your code, `new String('Hello World')`, is an instantiation of a string object - I don't see how that would be considered a wrapper function by any logic at all.

---

A **wrapper function** is a design concept where a very minimal function is using another function to do it's "work" for it, sometimes using a slightly different set of arguments.

for example:

```
function power(x, y) {
  var res = 1;
  while(y--) {
    res *= x;
  }

  return res;
}

function square(x) {
  return power(x, 2);
}
```

In the code above `square` is a wrapper function.

Comment: Granted, it's a pretty loose term, but I wouldn't call `square` a wrapper function. It's more like a [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). The thing is, wrapper functions are such a silly thing that it's difficult to provide a useful example out of context. It's got more to do with some of the language nitty-gritty than actual _design patterns_.

Comment: @Guilherme - I agree, it's not a marquee example but it's the simplest one that came to mind that is at least relevant to demonstrate the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Wrappers are a loose term for a function that simply returns a value, with no computation. They are useful when we need a value, but not right away. Maybe the result is not ready yet when you define it, or you need some binding for the function to work (use of `this`).

Neither of the examples you provided is a wrapper function. The first one is simply an object instantiation (you're not even *creating* a function). It just so happens that the `String` constructor can take a string literal as an argument, which means it can work like the identity function. In the second, it's just some more elaborate contraption, but it's still function calling and computing things.

In general, wrapper functions are pretty useless out of context, and they're mostly a Javascript-specific thing, but consider the following:

```
let foo = null;
fetch('/my/api/call').then(function(res) {
  foo = res;
  getFoo(); // => [your object]
});

getFoo(); // => null 

function getFoo() {
  return foo;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the example:

```
function SimpleWrapper() {
    var self = this;
    initialize();

    function initialize() {
        self.SuperOuterAdd = SuperOuterAdd;
        self.OuterAdd = OuterAdd;
    }
    function SuperOuterAdd(a, b){
       console.log('Wrapper 2');
       return OuterAdd(a, b);
    }

    function OuterAdd(a, b){
       console.log('Wrapper 1');
       return _add(a, b);
    }

    function _add(a, b){
        return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
    }
}
```